# ASP.NET MVC Deployed project not working: Inheritance System.web.mvc.viewpage fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, viewpage

i have a MVC project which runs perfectly local. When I deploy to the production server I receive a compilation error:

```
BC30456: 'Title' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_index_aspx'.
```

It makes me think that the inheritance of System.Web.ViewPage(of T) fails somehow... The project is deployed under `http://server/ProjectName`. The website at `http://server/` works fine when deployed....

Can somebody assist? Thanks

**UPDATE**
Does everybody notice: "not a member of '**ASP**.views_home_index_aspx'. ?
Shouldn't this be "not a member of '**ProjectName**.views_home_index_aspx'. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got the MVC DLL in your projects BIN folder.

It is installed on your machine at
C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies

EDIT:
Does the class ASP.views_home_index_aspx inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage ?

EDIT 2:
Every page in a .net web application and/or MVC site is compiled into a class.
The class names are generated from the location of the file.
So views_home_index_aspx is the compiled class that represents your aspx file at views/home/index.aspx . It has converted the "/" and "." to underscores.

So your error is saying that, the compiled class that your page generates does not contain the Title member you are trying to access.

Is this a big error that your page throws with a stack trace? or do you get the error in visual studio. Can you post some code?

Comment: Yes it's there. I'm using a websetup deployment project and the assembly is found as dependency so it's automatically included. :(

Comment: You're getting close I think. I have /views/home/index.aspx. This page has an inherits attribute which says: "System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable(Of Models.Project))". However I cannot find the class views_home_index_aspx anywhere....

Answer (score 0):

Best go through [these](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/06/30/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-6-solve-404-compression-and-performance-problems.aspx) [posts](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-08-cs.aspx) just in case its something you have missed.

Comment: Thanks for the urls, but both sites don't mention anything related to this issue...